# GraphViewData não é reconhecido

Tags: android, android-studio

Seguinte. Estou tentando importar no projeto o GraphViewData, mas o Android não o reconhece. Isso ocorre mesmo eu tendo importado a biblioteca toda do GraphView e estar funcionando (com.jjoe64.GraphView.GraphView)
Alguém sabe como poderia resolver isso?!

Comment: Ana, você adicionou no seu build.gradle a diretiva de compile para a API? Ou importasse o .jar?

Comment: adicionei a seguinte linha no build.gradle: compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'. Nao importei o .jar

Comment: Assim que você adicionou, certificou de dar um compile no arquivo? A IDE pediu se você quis dar build?

Comment: sim sim. compilei e sincronizei o que tinha que fazer la